# change class of html

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to change the class of an element in js with puppeteer?

eg.

```
<div>'text'</div>
```

after

```
<div class="try">'text'</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
element.classList.add("my-class");
```

It will add your class